# How to move from ServiceLocator to Dependency Injection? Specific example

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, uwp, service-locator

The problem is moving from the `ServiceLocator` anti-pattern to `Dependency Injection`. In view of my inexperience, I can't shift the DI principle to the code implemented now.

## Summary

*The Summary section is optional for read. You may want to comment on something, advise.*

The main purpose of the program is the process of merging placeholder fields of specific information. Number of information makes need to have infrastructure around. Such as forms, services, database. I have some experience with this task. I managed to create a similar program based on `WinForms`. And it even works! But in terms of patterns, maintenance, extensibility, and performance, the code is terrible. It is important to understand that programming is a hobby. It is not the main education or job.

The experience of implementing the described task on `WinForms` is terrible. I started studying patterns and new platform. The starting point is `UWP` and `MVVM`. It should be noted that the binding mechanism is amazing.

The first problem on the way was solved independently. It is related to navigation in the `UWP` via the `NavigationView` located in the `ShellPage` connected with `ShellViewModel`. Along with creating a `NavigationService`. It is based on templates from `Windows Template Studio`.

Since there is a working `WinForms` program and its anti-pattern orientation, there is time and a desire to do *everything correctly*.

Now I'm facing an architecture problem. Called `ServiceLocator` (or `ViewModelLocator`). I find it in examples from `Microsoft`, including templates from `Windows Template Studio`. And in doing so, I fall back into the anti-pattern trap. As stated above, I don't want this again.

And the first thing that comes as a solution is `dependency injection`. In view of my inexperience, I can't shift the DI principle to the code implemented now.

## Current implementation

The start point of app `UWP` is `app.xaml.cs`. The whole point is to transfer control to `ActivationService`. Its task is adding `Frame` to `Window.Current.Content` and navigated to default page - `MainPage`. [Microsoft documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio/blob/master/docs/activation.md).

The `ViewModelLocator` is a singleton. The first call to its property will call constructor.

```
private static ViewModelLocator _current;
public static ViewModelLocator Current => _current ?? (_current = new ViewModelLocator());
// Constructor
private ViewModelLocator(){...}
```

Using `ViewModelLocator` with `View` (`Page`) is like this, `ShellPage`:

```
private ShellViewModel ViewModel => ViewModelLocator.Current.ShellViewModel;
```

Using `ViewModelLocator` with `ViewModel` is similar, `ShellViewModel`:

```
 private static NavigationService NavigationService => ViewModelLocator.Current.NavigationService;
```

## Moving to DI

`ShellViewModel` has `NavigationService` from `ViewModelLocator` as shown above. How can I go to DI at this point? In fact, the program is small. And now is a good time to get away from anti-patterns.

## Code

**ViewModelLocator**

```
private static ViewModelLocator _current;
public static ViewModelLocator Current => _current ?? (_current = new ViewModelLocator());

private ViewModelLocator()
{
    // Services
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<NavigationService>();

    // ViewModels and NavigationService items
    Register<ShellViewModel, ShellPage>();
    Register<MainViewModel, MainPage>();
    Register<SettingsViewModel, SettingsPage>();
}

private void Register<TViewModel, TView>()
    where TViewModel : class
    where TView : Page
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TViewModel>();
    NavigationService.Register<TViewModel, TView>();
}

public ShellViewModel ShellViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ShellViewModel>();
public MainViewModel MainViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
public SettingsViewModel SettingsViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<SettingsViewModel>();

public NavigationService NavigationService => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<NavigationService>();
```

**ShellPage** : Page

```
private ShellViewModel ViewModel => ViewModelLocator.Current.ShellViewModel;

public ShellPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // shellFrame and navigationView from XAML
    ViewModel.Initialize(shellFrame, navigationView);
}
```

**ShellViewModel** : ViewModelBase

```
private bool _isBackEnabled;
private NavigationView _navigationView;
private NavigationViewItem _selected;

private ICommand _itemInvokedCommand;
public ICommand ItemInvokedCommand => _itemInvokedCommand ?? (_itemInvokedCommand = new RelayCommand<NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs>(OnItemInvoked));

private static NavigationService NavigationService => ViewModelLocator.Current.NavigationService;

public bool IsBackEnabled
{
    get => _isBackEnabled;
    set => Set(ref _isBackEnabled, value);
}

public NavigationViewItem Selected
{
    get => _selected;
    set => Set(ref _selected, value);
}

public void Initialize(Frame frame, NavigationView navigationView)
{
    _navigationView = navigationView;
    _navigationView.BackRequested += OnBackRequested;

    NavigationService.Frame = frame;
    NavigationService.Navigated += Frame_Navigated;
    NavigationService.NavigationFailed += Frame_NavigationFailed;
}

private void OnItemInvoked(NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(SettingsViewModel));
        return;
    }

    var item = _navigationView.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>().First(menuItem => (string)menuItem.Content == (string)args.InvokedItem);
    var pageKey = GetPageKey(item);
    NavigationService.Navigate(pageKey);
}
private void OnBackRequested(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewBackRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    NavigationService.GoBack();
}

private void Frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    IsBackEnabled = NavigationService.CanGoBack;
    if (e.SourcePageType == typeof(SettingsPage))
    {
        Selected = _navigationView.SettingsItem as NavigationViewItem;
        return;
    }

    Selected = _navigationView.MenuItems
        .OfType<NavigationViewItem>()
        .FirstOrDefault(menuItem => IsMenuItemForPageType(menuItem, e.SourcePageType));
}
private void Frame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    throw e.Exception;
}

private bool IsMenuItemForPageType(NavigationViewItem item, Type sourcePageType)
{
    var pageKey = GetPageKey(item);
    var navigatedPageKey = NavigationService.GetNameOfRegisteredPage(sourcePageType);
    return pageKey == navigatedPageKey;
}

private Type GetPageKey(NavigationViewItem item) => Type.GetType(item.Tag.ToString());
```

**Update 1**

Am I wrong about the equality between `ServiceLocator` and `ViewModelLocator`?

> Called `ServiceLocator` (or `ViewModelLocator`)

Essentially, the current task is to connected `View` and `ViewModel`. `NavigationService` is beyond the scope of this task. So shouldn't it be in `ViewModelLocator`?

Comment: Are you looking to do DI or IOC?  I don't see a path for constructor injection as shown in  your sample code.

Comment: @Maess I want to move from "bad" ServiceLocator to "good" solution. The first and perhaps the only thing I find is Dependency Injection. And that's where it ends. If these are different, incompatible things, why are they mentioned together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Maess notes, the biggest challenge you face (right now) is refactoring the static dependencies into constructor injection. For example, your ShellViewModel should have a constructor like:

```
public ShellViewModel(INavigationService navigation)
```

Once you have done that, you can then set up a DI framework (like NInject) with all your dependencies (kind of like your SimpleIoC thing), and, ideally, pull one root object from the container (which constructs everything else). Usually that's the main view model of the application.

I've done this successfully on multiple projects, both WPF and UWP, and it works great. Only thing you have to be careful of is when creating view models at runtime (as you often do), do it by injecting a factory.